# how to apply groupby to calculate the mean of values in different groups

Tags: python, pandas

Here I have a dataframe like this(simplified example, the real df should be extended to over 3000 rows, and the number of groups in Y column might be larger than 20). What I want to do, is to group "code" by
"Y", and to calculate the mean of values in "X" for each group in Y, and finally to subtract the corresponding group mean from "X" of each code.

For example, for "00001.SZ", it belongs to group "3", and the mean of "X" value of each code in group 3 is (10+15)/2 = 12.5, and I would like it returns the value of 10-12.5 = -2.5

```
             X         Y
code                              
00001.SZ   10         3
00002.SZ   20         2
00003.SZ   15         2
00004.SZ   20         1
00005.SZ   15         3
00006.SZ   10         2
00007.SZ    5         1
00008.SZ    5         1
00009.SZ   10         2
00010.SZ   15         2
```

So my ideal result is

```
code                              
00001.SZ    -2.5
00002.SZ      6
00003.SZ      1
00004.SZ     10
00005.SZ     2.5
00006.SZ     -4
00007.SZ     -5
00008.SZ     -5
00009.SZ     -4
00010.SZ     1
```

I do wish I make myself clear and I would be very grateful if there is any help.

Comment: `df['X'] - df.groupby('Y').X.transform('mean')`